# Convert jquery function to js

Tags: javascript, jquery

can somebody help me with converting following code to plain js

```
  $(function() {
      var wheight = $(window).height(); //get height of the window
      $('.fullheight').css('height', wheight);

      $(window).resize(function() {
          var wheight = $(window).height();
          $('.fullheight').css('height', wheight);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", func, false )
window.addEventListener( "resize", func, false);

function func() {
    var wheight = window.outerHeight;
    var elems   = document.querySelectorAll('.fullheight');

    for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
        elems[i].style.height = wheight + 'px';
    }
}
```